# Change Periods of Time in FRED API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, api

I'm messing around with the FRED API and I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the period of the data I'm pulling in. For example, when I pull in GDP using the API, it comes out as quarterly, but I want it measured annually. On the FRED website, I can choose what period to measure the data in, but I can't figure out how to translate that to my GET requests when using the API. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Great question. Could you add a few code snippets of how you are pulling the data now?